# Upgraded to 21.10. Not able to navigate through windows(apps) in the activities overview using the usual arrow keys on my keyboard any more

Tags: gnome, upgrade, shortcut-keys

I recently upgraded to 21.10. I can't navigate through the windows in the activities overview anymore with the arrow keys the way i could do it before upgrading my distro. Has the new GNOME done away with this feature and i'll have to live with that? If not, how do i fix this so i can freely navigate through the windows in the activities overview like i used to do before the distro upgrade?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

What you experience is an annoying behavior where keys and the tab key to navigate in the overview using the keyboard only work if the mouse pointer happens to be within one of the windows. If the cursor is outside of that area, or within two windows, the arrow keys are dead. What works, though, is to hit <kbd>PgDn</kbd> then <kbd>PgUp</kbd> again. That moves to the next workspace and back again, and once back, the arrow keys will work. So all depends on where the mouse cursor happens to be when you open the overview.

That is obviously flaky and unpredictable behavior that breaks simple keyboard navigation using arrow keys in the Activities and Application overviews. This has been there for ever, afaik. If it is not yet known to the developers, it should be reported.

You always can move the keyboard focus using the <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>Alt</kbd>+<kbd>Tab</kbd> bar, but 1) nowbody knows (or wants to know) that awkward keyboard combination 2) it is an attention requiring additional step detracting from the user's main workflow and 3) there is no reason I can see why no straightforward support for moving between items in the overview screens could be available.

It does not bother me too much because I use <kbd>Alt</kbd>+<kbd>Tab</kbd> and the search field. However, it is a major breakage for users wanting to navigate the overviews with arrow keys. This way, interacting with these screens is efficient only with the mouse or touch screen.

Comment: Thanks for pointing out. I think i'll report it to the developers then. Btw I came to know about Compiz window manager but it seems to be outdated and not compatible with 21.10.There isn't any gnome shell extension for window-switching that is also compatible with my distro.  Do you know any alternative to a window management tool like it?